# f.select in Rails not applying Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following select element in a Rails form:

```
<%= f.select :customer_type, options_for_select(["Retail","Contractor","Dealer"]), class: "form-control" %>
```

Does anyone know why the bootstrap class: "form-control" is not rendering?

I'm guessing my syntax is wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), the method signature for `select` is:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

`html_options`, which is where your HTML attribute options like `:class` should go, comes after `options`, but you're omitting `options` and putting `html_options` right after `choices`. Try this instead:

```
<%= f.select :customer_type, options_for_select(["Retail","Contractor","Dealer"]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

P.S. If you're wondering why the method signature specifies `object`, but in actual use we never pass `object` (`method` is always first), it's because we're not actually calling this method directly. When we call `f.select(...)` inside a `form_for` block, Rails calls `select(f.object, ...)` for us.

Comment: that was it - thank you for the answer and the associated documentation.  Any chance you can explain the difference between choices and options?  I can't really figure that out from the doc.

Comment: `options` is a confusing name, unfortunately. It doesn't refer to the `<options>` HTML tags; it refers to the options that change the method's behavior. For example, we can pass `{ include_blank: true }` to make the first `<option>` blank, or `selected: 10` to make the option with value `10` selected by default.

Comment: Little thing is I you use options_for_select then on edit page it is not showing already select item from DB why?

Answer (score 2):

**Update** - if you're seeing this now using you'll need to put the class in an object:

```
<%= f.select :customer_type, options_for_select(["Retail","Contractor","Dealer"]), {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
```

Took me some time to figure it out so I figured it was worth a post :)